# Performance impact of Android Image x86 Atom vs x86_64 Atom on x64 host

Tags: android

I am using Android studio for android development and in the SDK manager I can see different flavors of System images. My question here is particularly about x86 Atom Image and x86_64 Atom image.

Also does the x86_64 Image mean the instruction set within the android is 64 bit or does it imply that this particular x86_64 image should be used on x64 bit host/development environment.

If I am on an x64 intel computer I can use both of the images, I wonder what difference will either of the images will have if any when I run them on x64 host/development machine.

Answer (score 6):

I've measured it and x86 is 10% faster than x86_64:

https://www.huwig.de/de/2021/01/07/android-emulator-x86-ist-10-schneller-als-x86_64/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Android SDK for Atom needs a special program [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), and inside that post it is said that it is a hardware-assisted hypervisor engine taking advantage of VT-x, so it will be able to perform virtualization for 64bit clients even if the host is 32bit. But of course, you'll need a processor with VT-x capability.