# Does x86_64 image of the emulator run faster as compare to x86 on 64 bit systems?

Tags: android-emulator

I wanted to know if x86_64 images are for 64bit systems

OR

Is there any other advantage to use these x86_64 android emulator images over x84 images?

Comment: x86 is 10% faster than x86_64. I gave the complete answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615498/2360984

Answer (score 7):

x86_64 images run only on 64 bit machines, while the x86 images run on both 32 and 64 bit machines.

Other than that, I've measured it and x86 is 10% faster than x86_64 on the same 64 bit machine:

https://www.huwig.de/de/2021/01/07/android-emulator-x86-ist-10-schneller-als-x86_64/

So using the x86_64 allows you to verify that your app works fine on the 64 bit images. If you don't need to test that, I recommend to use the x86 image for now.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple
  questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).
  Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn
  enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the
  question and flag for undeletion.

Comment: Is Android x86 also faster as x86_64 on a hypervisor like VirtualBox or QEMU, using a 64-bit computer?

Comment: Yes, x86 is faster than x86_64 using QEMU on a 64-bit computer

Answer (score -4):

x86_64 runs in the same level compare to x86 image, they are both native to the CPU, both in the hareware virtual technology accelation

Using x86 android images run as fast as ten times or more than arm images, the cpu benchmark will run as fast as native hardware but GPU performance is not very good

the only advantage is you can run your application faster

Comment: This does not answer the question. You compare x84 vs ARM. But the question was about x86 vs x86_64.

Comment: Ok, I made an mistake